# How to produce Particle System in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, particle-system

I am making game in which I want to add **smoke**, **flame** and **blast** effect. I am using `THREE.js` library for the game making. I tried lots of technique but can't find the result.
I tried `SPARK.js` library and the particle system of `THREE.js` itself but did not able to produce the desired results. I am using **r51** version of `THREE.js`. 
Any one can help in this regard.
Thanks

Comment: Spark.js is outdated and not compatible with latest versions of Three.js. I highly recommend using latest Three.js version, you won't get much support for older versions. This probably means you need to use only Three.js particle system without spark.js.  Then you should show what you have tried (your code), and provide a little bit of information; how exactly it is not working, and what is the desired result.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have recently written a Particle Engine that is capable of the special effects you described, which currently works with Three.js v.56:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Particle-Engine.html

and see the blog post http://stemkoski.blogspot.com/2013/06/creating-particle-effects-engine-in.html for related details.

[Update Sept. 2013] The Particle Engine has been greatly improved and is still undergoing development at http://squarefeet.github.io/ShaderParticleEngine/

Comment: That engine looks great, I'll try to use it today. I noticed some quirks (maybe z-buffer issues) in the clouds and smoke examples, sometime the particle flicker. Do you think this can be fixed?

Comment: Your right, I've also noticed the particle flicker in those examples. I bet it can be fixed, but I'm not sure how. If you come up with any ideas, please post here or let me know!

Comment: Anyone know any cool implementation of moving three.js fog? Please share links!

Comment: It looks like your particle library is no longer compatible with the latest version of ThreeJS. Any plans for updates?

Comment: Tried using it with latest threejs (r111) and nothing is seen on screen + there are several warning messages. is the lib deprecated or did I do something wrong? Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer's library no longer works with latest THREE.js (r111) and it seems to be abandoned.

Wrote my own lib if anyone interested:

https://github.com/RonenNess/partykals

Live demo: https://ronenness.github.io/partykals/demo/index.html